# How to Log the message after request callback in web service outbound gateway

Tags: web-services, spring-integration, gateway, outbound

can you help me on how I can print the request message before completing the webservice call and after request-callback

```
<int:chain input-channel="tmsoapInChannel" output-channel="dest-channel">
<ws:header-enricher>
    <ws:soap-action value="http://bnst.l/tm/TWebService/vrrrectieRequest"/>
</ws:header-enricher>
<ws:outbound-gateway uri="http://bnst.l/tm/TWebService" request-callback="WSAHeaderCallback"/>
</int:chain>


  <int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggit" log-full-message="true" channel="justLog" />
```

I have implemented doWithMessage, and would like to see what message is going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be better done via `ClientInterceptor`. However there is already built-in feature in the Spring WS project for you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/#logging

Or borrow an idea from the `PayloadLoggingInterceptor` and implement similar logic in the `ClientInterceptor`.

Comment: Created log4j.properties in resources. excluded spring boot starter logging, added spring boot starter log4j dependency. Logging is working -  TRACE [client.MessageTracing.sent] Sent request. Thanks Artem